# Intel server board S1200BTL: KVMoverIP?

Tags: intel, hardware, keyboard-video-mouse

Do I need to buy AXXRMM4LITE module in addition to server board S1200BTL to get KVM over IP functionallity, or is it already built in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to buy it, from [Intel® Remote Management Module 4 - technical product specification](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/CS-032452.htm):

> The Integrated BMC firmware supports keyboard, video, and mouse
>   redirection (KVM) over LAN. [...] This feature is only enabled when
>   the Intel® RMM4 Lite is present.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear from the specification of the motherboard.